# $ajax function not working on android 7

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, post

Could someone please explain to me why my post function in jQuery is not working on android 7.

I have already checked if the button 'submits', I get an alert correctly. So the ajax function fails.

This is my function:

```
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: ""+ajaxurl+"",
            cache: false,
            data: post_data,
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
            if( response.status == 'success' ) {
                // redirect user to the requested page
                window.location.href = post_data.req_url;
            }else if (response.status == 'error') {
                jQuery('#fade').show();
                jQuery('.popup_content').html('<p>' + response.msg + '</p>');
                jQuery('.popup-message').show();
            }
```

I also have tried the jQuery post function, but this gives the same problem.

My full code:

```
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo !stristr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www.' ) ? str_ireplace('www.', '', admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) : admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';


    jQuery(document).on("click", ".submit", function(e) {


    //alert('yes');

        var post_data = {
            action: 'age_restrictionValidateAgeRestriction',
            security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>',
            validate: <?php echo $banner['ID']; ?>,
            req_url: '<?php echo $plugin->the_plugin->get_current_page_url(); ?>',
            form: jQuery('#agecheck').serialize(),
            social_details: jQuery('#social_details').val()
        };

        var data = post_data;

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, post_data, function (response) { 
            console.log(response);
            if( response.status == 'success' ) {
                console.log(post_data.req_url); 
                // redirect user to the requested page
                window.location.href = data.req_url;
            }else if (response.status == 'error') {
                jQuery('#fade').show();
                jQuery('.popup_content').html('<p>' + response.msg + '</p>');
                jQuery('.popup-message').show();
            }
        },
        'json');

       /* $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: ""+ajaxurl+"",
            cache: false,
            data: post_data,
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
            if( response.status == 'success' ) {
                // redirect user to the requested page
                window.location.href = post_data.req_url;
            }else if (response.status == 'error') {
                jQuery('#fade').show();
                jQuery('.popup_content').html('<p>' + response.msg + '</p>');
                jQuery('.popup-message').show();
            }

        });*/

        return false;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Looking forward to any reply.. I am stuck at this one.

Comment: any errors you get?

Comment: How can I check on mobile android? It doesn't have a console. In normal browser on desktop, like firefox, chrome, etc no error. I

Comment: Change `else if (response.status == 'error') {` to an unconditional `else {`. An error will stand a better chance of being displayed.